# material ui datagrid a status menu in table cell

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I would like to add a column like Filled Status

But I cannot figure out how to do it from the docs, I feel like I have to use renderCell when setting up the column but I can't see how to accomplish it.

https://mui.com/components/data-grid/demo/

https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the renderCell property, which is more effective for substituting the content of a cell.

```
<DataGrid rows={[]} columns={[
  {
     field:"status",
     align:"center",
     headerName:"User status",
     renderCell({ row }){
        return <Menu>
          <MenuItem children="ACTIVE"/>
          <MenuItem children="INACTIVE"/>
         </Menu>
     }
  }
]} />
```